# Camel test template uses a different exchange than the one I send

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the following test:

```
public class MyTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
                "classpath:my-config.xml",
                });
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {

        Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("myId", "1234");
        MessageContentsList parameters = new MessageContentsList();
        parameters.add(0, "");
        parameters.add(1, "1234");
        exchange.getIn().setBody(parameters);

        System.out.println("exchange before = " + System.identityHashCode(exchange)); //1657040467

        template.send("direct:myRoute", exchange);

        Object object = exchange.getOut().getBody();

        System.out.println("result = " + object); //null
        System.out.println("exchange after = " + System.identityHashCode(exchange)); //1657040467

        assertFalse(exchange.isFailed());
    }
}
```

Here is the last step inside the route "direct:myRoute":

```
public void doSomething(Exchange exchange)
{
    System.out.println("exchange within = " + System.identityHashCode(exchange)); //1649140180

    exchange.getOut().setBody(1);
}
```

My routes are defined by `RouteBuilder` classes and I load them by

```
<camelContext id="mainContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <packageScan>
        <package>com.my.route</package>
    </packageScan>

</camelContext>
```

and also dynamically by code:

```
((CamelContext) applicationContext.getBean("mainContext")).addRoutes(routeBuilder);
```

As you can see, I cannot retrieve the output of the route when I call the route from the test, because within the test for some reason it is a different exchange object (however, the original exchange headers and properties are somehow copied to the exchange within the route).
This problem does not happen when I define the routes by XML.

Why is that and how could I retrieve the result of the route when I call it from a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I don't you think you can write like this.

```
template.send("direct:myRoute", exchange);
Object object = exchange.getOut().getBody();
```

It should ideally be:

```
    Exchange out=null;
    out=template.requestBody("direct:myRoute", exchange);
    String body=out.getOut().getBody();
```

For this to work you need to set the exchange pattern to InOut.
More info on the templates:
https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html

Comment: Did you mean `out=template.send(...)`? Otherwise your cannot compile. Anyway `out.getOut().getBody()` is still `null`. I think the way I used it still does work is because it actually returns the input exchange. But that's an implementation detail so of course it's better to do it the way you mentioned. But it still does not work. I cannot see any data on the output exchange.

Comment: Did you change the exchange pattern to InOut?

Comment: By the way, you can compile but you have to change to out=template.requestBody("direct:myRoute", "requestBody", Exchange.class);

Comment: I overlooked the part of InOut pattern. Thank you! Now it works!